# The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) error in xamarin forms UWP?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have created a project with SQLiteConnection in xamarin.Forms. In UWP, I have implemented the following interface to return the SQLiteConnection

```
 public class SQLiteImplementation : ISQLite
{
    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var dbName = "db_sqlnet.db";
        var path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbName);
        return new SQLiteConnection(path);
    }
}
```

I have referred sqlite-net-pcl in my UWP project. But I have got the following error while running the project , "System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)    at Sample.UWP.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)" error in xamarin forms UWP"

How to resolve the above error? am I doing wrong in my code or it is because of reffered assembly?

Comment: I think it is one of the assemblies referenced is the wrong version

Comment: Have you tried updating `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` version?

Comment: news on this post?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to a regression bug that has been fixed in https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/1.5.166-beta

Try to update to that beta version and it should work.